# Determining the limit $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos(x+h) - \cos(x)}{(x+h)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}}$

Tags: limits

Determine the limit:

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos(x+h) - \cos(x)}{(x+h)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}}$$

After taking the conjugate, I got:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\big(\cos(x+h) - \cos(x)\big)\big((x+h)^{1/2} + x^{1/2})\big)} h$$

I took the conjugate of this, but I don't see how I can
cancel out the $h$.

Any tips?

Comment: Apologizes, didn't mean to put an equal sign

Comment: Notice my edits for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

You're supposed to spot derivatives here. Write your quotient as

$$\frac{\cos(x+h)-\cos x}{h}\cdot\frac{h}{(x+h)^{1/2}-x^{1/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos(x+h) - \cos(x)}{(x+h)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}} = \frac{\lim_{h\to0} \Big(\cos(x+h) - \cos x\Big) / h}{\lim_{h\to0} \Big( (x+h)^{1/2} - x^{1/2} \Big) / h} = \frac{\dfrac d {dx} \cos x }{\dfrac d {dx} x^{1/2}} = \cdots\cdots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Simpler $$\frac{\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)}{(x+h)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}}\times\frac{(x+h)^{1/2} + x^{1/2}}{(x+h)^{1/2} + x^{1/2}}=\frac{\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)}{h}[(x+h)^{1/2} + x^{1/2}]$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}=\dfrac{x+h-x}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}=?$$

and Use  [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)  $$\cos(x+h)-\cos x=-2\sin\dfrac h2\sin\dfrac{2x+h}2$$

Finally, $\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$